# Summary of lme4 model in function (lmerTest)

Tags: r, summary, lme4

If one has the following data

```
d = data.frame(out=rnorm(10), explain=rnorm(10), age=rnorm(10), sex=sample(c("M", "F"), size=10, replace=T), group=rep(c(1:5), 2))
f = as.formula("out ~ explain + age + sex + (1|group)")
```

and wants to fit a linear model with lme4 you can do

```
require(lme4)
require(lmerTest)
m  = lmer(f, d)
s  = summary(m)
```

That works, good.... But if the model is fitted within another function like

```
gglm = function(form, data){
    lm = lmer(form, data=data)
    return(lm)
}
m2 = gglm(f, d)
s2 = summary(m2)
```

I get an error.

```
summary from lme4 is returned
some computational error has occurred in lmerTest
```

Apparently, this is because the fitting of the model was done with a object called `data`, which is not visible in the outer scope. So if I do `data = d` I get the same result as before. However, if I do

```
data = data.frame(out=rnorm(10), explain=rnorm(10), age=rnorm(10), sex=sample(c("M", "F"), size=10, replace=T), group=rep(c(1:5), 2))
```

instead and get different data, the result of the summary is wrong.

This seems not to be the best way to do it and i think its easy to make mistakes. The normal `lm` and its according `summary` functiondon't have this problem. Isn't there a way to make the `lmerTest` summary less error prone?

Comment: Looks like a scoping problem. You should submit a bug report.

Comment: It's probably a bug, but check if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778773/using-predict-in-a-function-call-with-nlme-objects-and-a-formula helps.

Answer (score 2):

The do.call trick works (but it is a workaround, for sure).

```
gglm = function(form, data){
  lm = do.call(lmer, list(formula=form, data=data))
  return(lm)
}
m2 = gglm(f, d)
s2 = summary(m2)
```